# "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by" while using get_stylesheet_directory_uri()

Tags: child-theme, directory, include

I have a very strange problem while trying to include a custom file to my child theme. if I try to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` along with `require` it crashes the website. if I try to `var_dump(get_stylesheet_directory_uri);` then shows but PHP errors starts popping up.

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by - it points
>   the location where I add the require, var_dump. Without it, there are
>   not any errors

Am I not supposed to add a completely new file to the child theme?

Comment: Where exactly are you requiring the file?

Comment: @Raba I tried in the main plugin folder as well as subfolder. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() seems unusable

Comment: Can you please clarify what file you've placed your code in, and your full code? It's not clear from the information you have provided so far what the issue might be.